# Can MS Edge IE Mode be disabled by content?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

We're developing a React site for an organization that has enabled Edge IE Compatibility mode via group policy for the domain that our site is hosted at. We'd like to support the Edge browser, but IE compatibility mode presents a challenge. We very much prefer that Edge display our site chromium mode. Is there any way to disable compatibility mode in content - something like adding a meta tag? Or does the group policy make this non-negotiable?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to disable IE mode in code. You can only control it using group policy. If you want to run the site in normal Edge mode, you can only ask the organization to remove your site from the IE mode list.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the reply.